# Newly defined environment swallows the text it contains

Tags: environments

I want to define an environment to format test directions. So I do this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{directions}
{   
    \noindent \fbox{    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
}
{       
    \end{minipage}
}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{directions}

        \lipsum[1]

    \end{directions}

\end{document}
```

Text in that environment does not appear in the compiled document, and I get a `forgotten \endgroup` error (and also an `extra } inserted` error). I'm pretty sure I've closed all the braces; where did I go wrong?

Comment: What are the brackets `}{` in `minipage` supposed to match? After commenting them out, the example compiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `\framebox` is not properly closed. in the first part of new environment you should collect content of new environment in some `\savebox` and than it use in the second part inside of `\framebox`. see the following example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \newsavebox\directbox
\newenvironment{directions}
    {
    \begin{lrbox}{\directbox}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    }{
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
    \framebox{\usebox\directbox}
      }


\begin{document}
    \begin{directions}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{directions}
\end{document}
```

[image]